# Getting error while sending foreign key in json in Springboot REST API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am making a simple application. It has two entities i.e Book and Address. Book has author instance because they have one to one relationship. If I am sending author instance in with book it is working fine but When I am sending already exisiting author id I am getting Persistent Object Exception. Please help me.

```
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Author author;

    public Book(Long id,String title,Author author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }}

@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Author(Long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }}


@Service
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository repository;

    public List<Book> find() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Book find(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public Book save(Book book) {
        return repository.save(book);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Book> find(){
        return bookService.find();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "{id}")
    public Book find(@PathVariable Long id){
        return bookService.find(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Book find(@RequestBody Book book){
        return bookService.save(book);
    }
}
```

Json Response I am sending:

{
"title" : "Hello Java",
"author" : {
"id": 1
}
}

Comment: one author can have multiple books right?  or for your application, you are having this one to one relationship

Comment: I am having one to one relationship. one author can have one book

Comment: When I am sending new author in json object It is working fine. But If I am sending id of already existing author in json object I am getting persisting exception

Comment: @TameerHussain Can you please show me your `controller` or `serviceImpl`?

Comment: I have updated the code please check it.

Comment: Basically I want both persist and merge cascade

Comment: If you add only book then it work fine?

Comment: Yes and also if i add new author it is working fine but when i am trying to save with author id which already exists I am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Give complete author object in the JSON response instead of giving only his id like,

```
{ "title" : "Hello Java", "author" : { "firstName": "something", "lastName":"something"} }
```

Do this, don't give author id then object with your required author name will get created.

Comment: Your anwer give error `detached entity passed to persist: com.rest.RestApiPojo.Entity.Author; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.rest.RestApiPojo.Entity.Author`

Comment: edit or remove it before anyone downvoted